# wifi gesture recognition,dl,ml, python, cnn,

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, wifi, conv-neural-network

I have dataset look like this 
(7500, 200, 30, 3)

which 7500 samples (there are a tensor of shape 200,30,3) which is related to CSI data (kind of wifi data for gesture recognition) It has 150 different labels (gestures) the aim is to classify 
I used a CNN by keras  to classify, I faced with huge overfitting

```
   def create_DL_model():
    # input layer
    csi = Input(shape=(200,30,3))
    # first feature extractor
    x = Conv2D(64, kernel_size=3, activation='relu',name='layer1-01')(csi)
    x=BatchNormalization()(x)
    x = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2),name='layer1-02')(x)
    x = Conv2D(64, kernel_size=3, activation='relu',name='layer1-03')(x)
    x=BatchNormalization()(x)
    x = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2),name='layer1-04')(x)
    x=BatchNormalization()(x)
    x = Conv2D(64, kernel_size=3, activation='relu',name='layer1-05',padding='same')(x)
    x=Conv2D(32, kernel_size=3, activation='relu',name='layer1-06',padding='same')(x)
    x=Conv2D(64, (3,3),padding='same',activation='relu',name='layer-01')(x)
    x=BatchNormalization()(x)
    x=MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2, 2,),name='layer-02')(x)
    x=Conv2D(32, (3,3),padding="same",activation='relu',name='layer-03')(x)
    x=BatchNormalization()(x)
    x=MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2, 2),name='layer-04')(x)
    x=Flatten()(x)
    x=Dense(16,activation='relu')(x)
    keras.layers.Dropout(.50, seed=1)
    probability=Dense(150,activation='softmax')(x)
    model= Model(inputs=csi, outputs=probability)
    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='sgd', metrics=['accuracy'])
    return model
```

as you see, I used drop out for dense layer, early stopping  and batch normalization for fight with overfitting, as you see still, there is the problem

[image]

after cross validation, I have accuracy around 70 (some papers got 90 pecent accuracy however we have 150 labels and it seems 90 pecent it is really grear result, they used meta-learning which I could not use), is there any way that you can recommend

many thanks

Comment: 7500 are kinda few samples, especially with 150 labels. Even if they are balanced (50 per label) this does not work I think. Speaking of which, verify class balance. Try augmenting and shuffling data. Dropout might be a tad high at .50,,,

Comment: tnx for your quick response, it is balanced,  I shuffled data, randomly order, do you mean this ? what do you mean of augmentation here, you mean adding noise or ..?                                                 
 you are right, that why the authors' used meta-learning approach, Is there any way that you can recommend to implement meta learning by keras in python

Comment: Well by augmentation I was very vague... you have to find your own way to artificially increase samples, because more authentic samples are not available. Ok, try adding some very small noise to copies. Shuffling, as in feeding in random order is indeed ok. As for meta learning that is very broad....

Comment: tnx again for prompt response, can you let me know how can I use meta learning for this

Comment: Do you mean generally speaking? Or a framework called meta learning? I only know this definition as a generic concept...

Comment: @Attersson  I meant a framework called "meta-learning"  I can share with you a paper,

Comment: Ok post a link. I will try to help, if I can, when I have time

Answer (score 0):

The accuracy vs epoch graph signals the `over fitting` issue present in your model. This is due to few training samples (7500/150 = 50 per class). One possible solution could be applying `Data Augmentation` which allows you to build a powerful image classifier using only very few training examples.

**Data structure**

Store your data according to the following structure

```
data/
    train/
        class1/
            class1_img001.jpg
            class1_img002.jpg
        class2/
            class2_img001.jpg
            class2_img002.jpg
            ...
        class150/
            class150_img001.jpg
            class150_img002.jpg
            ...
    validation/
        class1/
            class1_img001.jpg
            class1_img002.jpg
        class2/
            class2_img001.jpg
            class2_img002.jpg
            ...
        class150/
            class150_img001.jpg
            class150_img002.jpg
            ...
```

You can do:

```
def create_DL_model(img_height, img_width, channel):
    # input layer
    csi = Input(shape=(img_height, img_width, channel))
    # first feature extractor
    x = Conv2D(64, kernel_size=3, activation='relu',name='layer1-01')(csi)
    x=BatchNormalization()(x)
    x = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2),name='layer1-02')(x)
    x = Conv2D(64, kernel_size=3, activation='relu',name='layer1-03')(x)
    x=BatchNormalization()(x)
    x = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2),name='layer1-04')(x)
    x=BatchNormalization()(x)
    x = Conv2D(64, kernel_size=3, activation='relu',name='layer1-05',padding='same')(x)
    x=Conv2D(32, kernel_size=3, activation='relu',name='layer1-06',padding='same')(x)
    x=Conv2D(64, (3,3),padding='same',activation='relu',name='layer-01')(x)
    x=BatchNormalization()(x)
    x=MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2, 2,),name='layer-02')(x)
    x=Conv2D(32, (3,3),padding="same",activation='relu',name='layer-03')(x)
    x=BatchNormalization()(x)
    x=MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2, 2),name='layer-04')(x)
    x=Flatten()(x)
    x=Dense(16,activation='relu')(x)
    keras.layers.Dropout(.50, seed=1)
    probability=Dense(150,activation='softmax')(x)
    model= Model(inputs=csi, outputs=probability)
    return model

from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

batch_size = 32
img_height = 200
img_width = 30
channel = 3

model = create_DL_model(img_height, img_width, channel) 

# this is the augmentation configuration we will use for training
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
        rotation_range=40,
        width_shift_range=0.2,
        height_shift_range=0.2,
        rescale=1./255,
        shear_range=0.2,
        zoom_range=0.2,
        horizontal_flip=True,
        fill_mode='nearest')


# this is the augmentation configuration we will use for testing:
# only rescaling
test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)

# this is a generator that will read pictures found in
# subfolers of 'data/train', and indefinitely generate
# batches of augmented image data
train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        'data/train',  # this is the target directory
        target_size=(img_height , img_width ),  # all images will be resized
        batch_size=batch_size,
        class_mode='categorical_crossentropy')  

# this is a similar generator, for validation data
validation_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        'data/validation',
        target_size=(img_height , img_width ),
        batch_size=batch_size,
        class_mode='categorical_crossentropy')

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='sgd', metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit_generator(
        train_generator,
        steps_per_epoch=7500// batch_size,
        epochs=50,
        validation_data=validation_generator,
        validation_steps=YOUR_VALIDATION_SIZE// batch_size) # use YOUR_VALIDATION_SIZE as per your validation data
model.save('model-e50-b32.h5')  # always save your weights after training or during training
```

The number of CNN layers can be decreased and accuracy-loss can be monitored since we are only feeding 7500 training images.

The above code is not tested. Please share your errors for further advice.

More about data augmentation and how to apply is [here](https://blog.keras.io/building-powerful-image-classification-models-using-very-little-data.html).